# How do I detect the COM port number of a usb dongle?

Tags: java, sms

I have created an application which sends SMS using Java.

Whith this, I must enter the com port number of dongle manually to code segment.

I would like to do this automatically using code.

How can I do this?

Comment: I added the sms tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at jUSB, which provides an API for USB programming. Get a `Host` from a `HostFactory`, iterate over it's `Bus`es, and walk the device tree (you can get the number of devices from each Device, #0 is usually the device itself). Then you just need to find out what kind of Configuration your device has and search by that.